# C# creating a CSV file so contents of one field wraps in a cell

Tags: c#, excel

I have two databases one is the master and one is the detail, 
table1 is the master and table2 being the detail.
table2 has comments and dates on when the comments were added.

My problem: 
I have to export out a CSV file (C#) and have all the comments in one field.
I can do this, however my boss is importing this into excel and would like the have a carriage return (or something) at the end of each comment so they wrap in one cell

The comments are formatted like this: "**11/10/201: comment1 11/10/2011: comment two**"

when it get imported into excel I would like to comments to auto wrap so they look like this in the excel cell:

**11/10/2011: comment1 
11/10/2011: comment two**

I try the **\r** and the **\n** but then excel place the comment into a separate cell.

any help would be great.

Comment: Look at my answer bellow, but if you still have problems, try to post C# code that fails...

Comment: You mean you want the text in a cell to be wrapped in the cell? It maybe more beneficial to show a screen shot image of what you want because the two comments (before and after importing in excel) look exactly the same. And yes \r and \n and most likely even \t will put them in a separate cell

Comment: Okay there is no error :-)  your second comment is correct once imported into excel I would like to have one of my fields to wrap at a certain spot, i'm not sure how to post a screen shot here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is a line feed, or \n. You should also make sure the cell has:

```
   myCell.Style.IsTextWrapped = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting to .csv, then wrap each field with double quote characters ("). Inside of this, double up any existing double quotes ( `.Replace("""", """""")` )

You need to have the pattern `","` separating fields, with an opening and closing quote.

This will preserve existing line breaks when brought into Excel. If you need line breaks, then insert Environment.NewLine's where needed.

With a .csv, you do not have many options to specify cell formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping values which contain line breaks in double quotes (making sure you first replace double quotes with two double quotes), but if you do it in CSV then your boss will complain that cells with a line break in only show the first line in excel.

There are numerous open source and commercial packages that let you create excel directly, which would probably overcome these problems.

Answer (score 0):

To Have:

```
Row 1 Col1 | Row1 Col2
-----------+----------
Row 2 Col1 | Row2
           | Col2 (different line)
```

The minimal CSV is:

```
Row1 Col1,Row1 Col2
Row2 Col1,"Row2
Col2 (different line)"
```

The `"` marks it as a block within which newlines and commas are not part of the CSV markup, but actual content. You also need to do this anywhere you use " and also escape it  by doubling. So

```
This cell says "hello" to you
```

is escaped as

```
"This cell says ""hello"" to you"
```

The easiest way to do this in practice, is to ignore the fact that you don't always need to do it, and just do it every time:

```
public static string CSVEscape(string content)
{
  return "\"" + content.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
}
```